# Updating cell numbers from a web page

Tags: excel

Need a little preliminary pointing at the right direction.

I have a web page that requires a login. One logged in, I get a page of statistics.

I'd like to have an excel spreadsheet that has a button on it. When the button is pressed, some script, will go on to that website, automatically login and put some data from the web page into the spreadsheet.

What's the best way to proceed about this technically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/248914/embed-web-component-text-in-excel/249360#249360)